# extension of complex numbers n

Tags: complex-analysis

You can introduce the imaginary unit , then you can introduce the quaternions. Now somebody has introduced n-imaginary units for sure, what is the term.

I want to read about it .
Tell me. Please

Comment: Look up octonions and sedenions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biquaternion

Comment: Please don't "sign" your messages. Your signature already appears in the bottom right of every post you make.

Comment: You might also be interested in reading about *Clifford algebras*.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Cayley-Dickson construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction), which in some sense continues the sequence indefinitely. However, the algebras become progressively less well-behaved beyond the first one or two steps. The quaternions are not commutative, and the next element in the series, the octonions, are not even associative!